# Generate Script Of Database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, scripting

How to Create Script for the Database Objects in SQL server 2008 r2 and restore it in database.

Comment: Hi, First of all, welcome to the site. There are a few problems with your question preventing answers and attracting downvotes. Please show all the code and table definitions and sample data. Please do the [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) read through the [help section](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this site works. especially how to [ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will attract more answers and useful feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pre-requisites**

This article assumes knowledge of SQL Server.

In SQL Server the required database has various tables with data. Here we use the "`Address-Book`" database.

**STEP 1**

Choose the database to create a database script in the "`Object Explorer`" section of SQL Server.
And choose the following option in sequence for generating a script.

[image]

**STEP 2**

We choose which object you want to generate a script for in the "Generate And Published Script" Wizard.

The first step is to describe how many steps are necessary to generate a script.

A. **Introduction**

There are the following `four` steps to complete this wizard:

```
1. Select database object.

2. Specify scripting or publishing options.

3. Review your selection.

4. Generate a script, then save or publish it.
```

B. **Choose Object**

Select a database object to script. There the following `two` options:

**Using the first option:** (script an entire database and all database objects) we generate a script for the entire database.

**Using the second option:** (to select a specific database object) we generate a script of specific database objects, like tables, Store Procedure, View and so on.

Here we select the table objects in our database.

[image]

C. **Set Scripting Option**

In this window we select a location to store our script. If you want to rename a script file then rename it with a custom name. If you want to generate a database script without tables data then click on the "Next" Button.

If we want a database script with table data then we must use the setting for generating a script with "`Tables Data`".

Click on the "`Advanced`" option  In the Advanced Scripting Window,  select "`Type Of Data To Script`" with the "`Schema and Data`" option.

[image]

The default location for storing the script file is *"C:\Users......\Documents\script.sql".*

Click on "`Next`" to continue.

[image]

D. **Review Your Selection**

In the Wizard Window click on the "`Next`" button to continue.

E. **Save Or Publish Script**

In the Wizard Window click on the "`Finish`" button.

**Restore Data**

We will now restore a database. To do that we require the same name (that we used for the database script). Of "Blank Database" to restore it. If you want to use an existing same name database then you must "Drop All Database Tables".

Now open a "script.sql" with Notepad and copy the entire script from the Notepad file.
Now return to SQL Server and click on "New Query" [image] and paste onto the entire code in the Query Wizard.
After pasting it execute the query [image]

Finally, we get the message "`Query Executed Successfully`". We have restored our database successfully.

[image]

**Summary**

Now in this Question-Answer we learned how to manage our database and secure it.

I hope this helps you. I will try my best.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you the author of [this article?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1b29b1/generate-script-of-database-in-sql-server-2008/) In any case, suggest you add attribute and a link. You probably want to change the wording a bit, too. In the link it's an article, here it's an answer to a question.

Comment: Why open the script in Notepad and then copy & paste it into a New Query window in SSMS if you can open the script in SSMS directly?